# Upgrading Rails application to bootstrap3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

Hi I have been following Michael Hartl's book for developing rails applications. I have reached the end and I want to start using Bootstrap3 with the app I've developed.

I have followed the instructions on https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass but this has not worked. The gem has installed correctly and I can get it to work on my local environment by changing my application.css --> application.css.scss and adding the import "bootstrap" statement to the file along with having it in custom.css.scss. This doesn't seem right and it doesn't work when I deploy to Heroku either.

The set up I am trying to get work is as follows.

Gem file

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'pg'

gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'childprocess'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'growl'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

application.css

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all    the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

custom.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";

/*mixins, variables etc. */
$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

@mixin box_sizing{
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
...
...
```

Ideally I think I should be changing application.css to .css.scss and having importing bootstrap there without needing it in my custom.css.scss too. This is causing an error when deploying to Heroku, that is saying that application.css is already required.

**UPDATE**

As per the advice bellow I have removed

```
Import "bootstrap";
```

from custom.css.scss and added it to the renamed application.css.scss. This now looks like

`@import "bootstrap";
@import "custom";`

I cleared the tmp folder using

```
rake tmp:clear
```

and then refreshed the page.

Individually importing the css.scss files seems to have solved my problems

Comment: If I can recall correctly you must import `twitter/bootstrap`. However it's strange if you don't get any errors.

Comment: I had Bootstrap 2 set up before on my app would this be affecting it? I thought the gem would install bootstrap for me without me needing to manually import the bootstrap files?

Comment: I'm so sorry my comments is valid for a deprecated version of bootstrap sass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the solution you proposed yourself, that is to use `application.css.scss` instead of `application.css` and use `@import` instead of `require` as mentioned in the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives):

> If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the
>   Sass @import rule instead of these Sprockets directives. Using
>   Sprockets directives all Sass files exist within their own scope,
>   making variables or mixins only available within the document they
>   were defined in. You can do file globbing as well using @import "*",
>   and @import "**/*" to add the whole tree equivalent to how
>   require_tree works. Check the sass-rails documentation for more info
>   and important caveats.

check `sass-rails`' [documentation](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) for more.

Comment: Hi I have updated the original question after trying what you have suggested here

Comment: After realising there was a mistake in custom.css.scss and then clearing the temp using rake tmp:clear. I have updated the original Q with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try it maybe with

```
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails
```

Please note to choose the bootstrap3 branch, like

```
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rail", git: "git@github.com:seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git", branch: "bootstrap3"
```